# Spring MVC: Is regular expression possible to map static contents in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

I want to make a dynamic key for my static resource, here is my application

I have a web application (Spring MVC), most of its jsp pages serve static resource like images, js and css etc, These resources are cached. So whenever I modify css or js, I just change that key so that web page request for files on different new path.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.my.package" })
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    //... some code ...

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/here-is-a-key/resource/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/")
                .setCachePeriod(2592000);//30 days
    }

    //... some code ...

}
```

This will serve static resource like

```
/static/here-is-a-key/resource/js/app.js
```

Whenever I make changes in static resources (images,css, js), I also change the key

This helps browser or webpage to request fresh resources. (not cached)
**It works perfect**,

but issue comes for the servers or browsers that caches the html page(google etc), in that cached html page the key saved was old-key which does not `map` anything anymore, and 404 exception is thrown.

I want this part to be ignored some wild-card functionality

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/(.*?)/resource/**")
.addResourceLocations("/static/")
```

so that it matches cached path as well as new path.
So any contents like

```
/static/key001/resources/** get mapped to /static/
/static/key002/resources/** also mapped on /static/
```